# Array loop for Object.keys and its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to show an array loop in which i have a date and its value. I am able to loop Objects.keys of an array but inner loop need to show the key array individualy. Its a task of simple arrays but i'm unable to figure it out.
following is my code.

```
var arr = {
    '2016-03-06' : ['1', '2','3','4','5'],          // 6th march 2016
    '2016-03-07' : ['6','7','8','9','10','11'],     // 7th march 2016
    '2016-03-08' : ['2','3','4','5'],           // 8th march 2016
    '2016-03-09' : ['6','7','8','9','10','11'],     // 9th march 2016
    '2016-03-10' : ['1', '2','3'],          // 10th march 2016
    '2016-03-11' : ['6','7','8','9','10','11'],     // 11th march 2016
};

var a=0;
var b=0;
ab = Object.keys(arr).length;
bc = Object.keys(arr)[b].length;
console.log(ab);
console.log(bc);

for(a=0; a < ab; a++){
    $('.result .array').append('<li data-date="'+Object.keys(arr)[a]+'">'+ Object.keys(arr)[a] + '</li>');
    for(b=0; b < Object.keys(arr).length; b++){
        $('.result .array').append('<li data-date='+ Object.keys(arr)[a]  +'>1</li>');
    }
}
```

Comment: As a quick note, you desperately need to do away with those variable names.  Variables should always be intelligible to a person reading your code (including yourself) so `ab` should be named `objectLength` and `bc` should be named `firstIndexLength`, etc.

Comment: what is your required output?

Comment: What is purpose of nested `for` loops ?

Comment: Note: Its a bad practice to append in loop. Also `Object.keys(arr)[b]` this will always give you `10`. Its length of `2016-03-06` and not `['1', '2','3','4','5']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eveyrthing becomes clear when you name things:

```
var arr = {
    '2016-03-06' : ['1', '2','3','4','5'],          // 6th march 2016
    '2016-03-07' : ['6','7','8','9','10','11'],     // 7th march 2016
    '2016-03-08' : ['2','3','4','5'],           // 8th march 2016
    '2016-03-09' : ['6','7','8','9','10','11'],     // 9th march 2016
    '2016-03-10' : ['1', '2','3'],          // 10th march 2016
    '2016-03-11' : ['6','7','8','9','10','11'],     // 11th march 2016
};

for (var date in arr) {
    console.log('there are %s hours in %s:', arr[date].length, date);
    for (var hour in arr[date]) {
        console.log('- %s', arr[date][hour])
    }
}
```

Where:

- `arr.length` is the entire object length;
- `arr[date]` is the entire array;
- `arr[date].length` is the length of the array;
- `date` is the label of object;
- `arr[date][hour]` is a value from your arrays;

Comment: what if i want to show the array values rather then length?

Comment: '2016-03-06' : ['1', '2','3','4','5'] it gives the counter of array i want to show 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (this is the value) not 0,1,2,3,4 (this is the length)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for such output:

```js
var arr = {
    '2016-03-06' : ['1', '2','3','4','5'],          // 6th march 2016
    '2016-03-07' : ['6','7','8','9','10','11'],     // 7th march 2016
    '2016-03-08' : ['2','3','4','5'],           // 8th march 2016
    '2016-03-09' : ['6','7','8','9','10','11'],     // 9th march 2016
    '2016-03-10' : ['1', '2','3'],          // 10th march 2016
    '2016-03-11' : ['6','7','8','9','10','11'],     // 11th march 2016
};

for (var key in arr) {
    
  $('.result .array').append('<li data-date="'+key+'">'+ key + '</li>');

  var associatedData = arr[key];
  if($.isArray(associatedData)){
    for (var i = 0; i < associatedData.length; i++) {
      $('.result .array').append('<li data-date='+ associatedData[i]  +'>'+associatedData[i]+'</li>');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result">
  <div class="array">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes. simple and easy.. yes i was looking for this result

Answer (score 0):

```
for(b=0; b < Object.keys(arr).length; b++){
        $('.result .array').append('<li data-date='+ Object.keys(arr)[a]  +'>1</li>');
    }
```

right here, `Object.keys(arr)[a]`, this needs to be `Object.keys(arr)[b].`

You are using the a increment twice instead of a and b both once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.forEach` to loop over `Keys` or `currentItem`.

Also as I have already mentioned, its a bad practice to append element in a loop. You should instead create a html string and perform bulk operation.

```js
var arr = {
    '2016-03-06' : ['1', '2','3','4','5'],          // 6th march 2016
    '2016-03-07' : ['6','7','8','9','10','11'],     // 7th march 2016
    '2016-03-08' : ['2','3','4','5'],               // 8th march 2016
    '2016-03-09' : ['6','7','8','9','10','11'],     // 9th march 2016
    '2016-03-10' : ['1', '2','3'],                  // 10th march 2016
    '2016-03-11' : ['6','7','8','9','10','11'],     // 11th march 2016
};
var html = "";

for (var k in arr){
  html+= '<li data-date="'+k+'">'+ k + '</li>';
  
  if(Array.isArray(arr[k])){
    arr[k].forEach(function(item){
      html += '<li data-date="'+item+'">'+ item + '</li>';
    });
  }
};

$('.result .array').append(html)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result">
  <div class="array">
  </div>
</div>
```